# What's the value of default-directory during startup?

Tags: start-up

I'm looking through [startup.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/startup.el), and normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path references the [default-directory](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/startup.el#L448) variable.

What's the value of that variable during startup? I searched for calls to normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path and only found a 2-line file site-lisp/subdirs.el

```
(if (fboundp 'normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)
    (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```

I tried inserting some debugging statements to get more insight, but so far they haven't worked. First I tried adding:

```
(message "%s" default-directory)
```

and byte recompiling the file. Restarted Emacs but I saw no trace of my debugging in the Messages buffer. Then I replaced the above line with:

```
(with-temp-file "/Users/ivan/emacswhereami"
  '(insert default-directory))
```

Comment: The answer is in the doc-string for `normal-top-level-add-to-load-path`:  "*This function is called from a subdirs.el file.  It assumes that 'default-directory' is the directory in which the subdirs.el file exists, and it adds to 'load-path' the subdirs of that directory as specified in DIRS.  Normally the elements of DIRS are relative.*"

Comment: @lawlist Right you are, thanks! Impatience got the better of me. I should have just kept reading a little farther.